# How to open a file from VS code terminal without typing

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

E.g. below is in VS code terminal, how can I open the `EditDialog.js` without typing. I recalled I was able to click the line itself, but now failed

```
[1] ./src/models/document/EditDialog.js
[1]   Line 2:8:    'Typography' is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
[1]   Line 3:8:    'Button' is defined but never used                 no-unused-vars
[1]   Line 5:8:    'DialogActions' is defined but never used          no-unused-vars
[1]   Line 7:8:    'DialogTitle' is defined but never used            no-unused-vars
[1]   Line 15:19:  'Model' is assigned a value but never used         no-unused-vars
[1]   Line 23:9:   'handleUpdate' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the VS Code docs, it looks like using Ctrl+click (or Cmd+click on macs) on file paths in the terminal should do the trick!

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_create-or-open-a-file